# Views displaying content with link to en-US when it shouldn't

Tags: views, i18n-l10n

We have a site that has all its content translated for American English. Detection is through the URL via `en-US/` been added to the paths.

I have a number of views returning content from specific content types and a couple of them are returning content with links to the `en-US/` version and for the life of me cannot figure out whats causing this.

The views have their rendering language set to `Rendering Language:
Content language of view row`.

I also have a filter on this view to ensure that I dont get duplicates showing, without it the view returns results containing the content from both "languages". Filter is `Translation language: (is one of) Interface text language selected for page`

What I have tried:

1. Turned view caching off
2. Tried changing to different combinations
   of the Rendering language and Translation Language filter.
3. Removing Filter
4. Running `drush cr all` after every change

The only way I can get the view to behave is by forcing the Rendering Language to `English` but this then is no good when you are wanting the en-US version.

Is there something else I haven't tried that may be an answer to my woes ?

**Additional info as requested by Mario Steinitz in comments**:

Two languages:
 1. en (Standard british english) which is default
 2. en-US translation (For American spellings of words, e.g. Inquire instead of Enquire)

By default when accessing the site with out the `en-US` prefix in the domain it will display the default British english. Adding `en-US` to the url should output the American translations of content.

Currently views I have are outputing the American version of any results, even when you are on the default language. All other content is fine, this is affecting my views only.

Also, $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] is ALWAYS set to be en-US locale which I think is where the problem is but I am unsure what is forcing this.

So my questions are:

1. Is there something Drupal is doing that is changing the HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE variable to always be en-US *(Even if you are on default language* (no `en-US` in path)*)* and would this affect the output of the view results ?
2. If HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE wouldn't affect the views is there something else that could?

Comment: I have also just noticed that my HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE variable is always set to en-US regardless....Unsure whats forcing this to be set like that.

Comment: I can't follow you (maybe it's because late night here), but you have a English site that is translated to American English and Views show American English links when viewing them in English? Could you please be a little more specific on what you expect to get and what you get instead? Are you viewing the Views in a different language? Also, is the entire View behaving like this or only some of its results? It would help greatly to be brief and specific for getting an answer.